# Error: Invalid postback or callback argument - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, postback, registration

I'm working with ASP.NET web application ,  i have a Registration form and whenever i tried to type the user `Username` this error shows up in the browser !

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I have tried to add `if(!IsPostBack){///Your Code.... }` in the `Page_Load` and it didn't work ! also i tried `EnableEventValidation="false"` in `web.config` again it didn't work ! please any help ?

registration form code :

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = "insert into Users (Username,Password,Email) values (@username, @password, @email)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Seller_Registration.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { Response.Write("error"); }
}
```

and my `web.config` code:

```
<pages validateRequest="true">
        <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<table align="left" class="auto-style8" dir="rtl">                             
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style13">username </td>
        <td class="auto-style10">
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Height="25px" Width="223px" ForeColor="#990033" OnTextChanged="TextBoxUsername_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style11">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" ErrorMessage="write username"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style13">password</td>
        <td class="auto-style10">
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="223px" ForeColor="#990033" TextMode="Password" OnTextChanged="TextBoxPassword_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style11">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword" ErrorMessage="must write the password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style13">confirm password </td>
        <td class="auto-style10">
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCPassword" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="223px" ForeColor="#990033" TextMode="Password" OnTextChanged="TextBoxCPassword_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style11">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxCPassword" ErrorMessage="must write the password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBoxPassword" ControlToValidate="TextBoxCPassword" ErrorMessage="wrong password"></asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style13">email</td>
        <td class="auto-style10">
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Height="25px" Width="223px" ForeColor="#990033" TextMode="Email" OnTextChanged="TextBoxEmail_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style11">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="must write email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="the email no valid" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="auto-style13">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style10">
            <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" OnClick="Button6_Click" Text="done" ForeColor="#990033" />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the ASPX (design, not code-behind) file?

Comment: @DaniloRamirez i have updated

Comment: Nope, that's not the one I mean. The one that looks like
<div>
         
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="width:224px">
            </asp:TextBox>
            
            <br />
            <br />
            
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enter..." style="width:85px" onclick="Button1_Click" />

</div>
...etc

Comment: @DaniloRamirez sorry , i just update it

Comment: Does your "TextBoxUsername_TextChanged" function follow this structure?
protected void TextBoxUsername_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        ...
}

Comment: @DaniloRamirez yes and it's empty function